# Wavelet Filter and Scaling Function

Tags: image-processing, scaling, wavelet, haar-wavelet

I am trying to plot the values of a symbol scaled between 0 and 1. 
The equations that satisfy these elements are as follows:-

```
h0^2+h1^2+h2^2+h3^2==1
h0*h2+h1*h3==0
h0+h1+h2+h3==sqrt(2)
h0-h1+h2-h3==0
h1-2*h2+3*h3==0
```

The absolute values of

```
h0 = ~0.966
h1 = ~1.673
h2 = ~0.448
h3 = ~0.25
```

The value of h1 is outside 0-1. How do I scale them so that the values are between 0-1.

Further, I need to find the scaling function and plot it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to plot the [Daubechies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daubechies_wavelet) scaling function of order 2 (with 4 coefficients) compare your filter taps to the ones used in this [cascade algorithm example](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/wavelet/cascade_test02.m) and check its [output](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/wavelet/cascade_test02.png). This is the algorithm that applies the scaling filter (and upsampling) to itself.

My guess is you are there if you use `h3 = -h3` and then divide all your filter taps by `sqrt(2)`.